# How can I put images in the gallery of the AVD?

Tags: android-emulator

everyone. Could somebody please tell me how to put pictures in the Gallery of the emulator? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You need follow these steps:

1. Locate you .img file of your adv. 
   By default, the android tool creates the AVD directory inside `~/.android/avd/` (on Linux/Mac), `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\` on Windows XP, and `C:\Users\<user>\.android\` on Windows 7 and Vista.

   see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#DefaultLocation
2. Mount it
3. Create Music and Pictures folders in the sdcar.
4. Move your .mp3 and images to that folders.

   see http://www.gphone.org.hk/cgi-bin/ch/topic_show.cgi?id=8&bpg=1&age=0
5. Restart the emulator